# Getting entities insted Null on empty result sets

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I'm getting the result set like:

```
$something = $this->contain('First.Second.Third');
```

If I have some data in the result I'm getting the entities correctly but if there is not any data in the DB I'm getting Null which causes "getting property of a non-object" errors in the templates. What I'm doing now is to assign new entities for each table like:

```
if(!$something->first)
{
    $something->first                = TableRegistry::get('First')->newEntity(); 
    $something->first->second        = TableRegistry::get('Second')->newEntity(); 
    $something->first->second->third = TableRegistry::get('Third')->newEntity();
}
```

How can I avoid doing this every time when I get empty result?

Answer (score 0):

Simply account for this possible scenario in your view templates, there's no need for any fancy workarounds, just test for `null` or emptiness, or use `Entity::has()`.